Hierarchy level based on Flag
In OBIEE Hierarchical development, we have a specific requirement where we need to implement a hierarchy based on a single dimension table. The hierarchy levels are defined as follows: account_group_name --> sub_account_group_name --> account_code. We also have a drill_down_flag column, which holds values 'Y' or 'N'. The hierarchy should only drill down to the next level if the drill_down_flag is 'Y'; otherwise, it should not drill down. How can this scenario be implemented in RPD development?
Nothing worked i tried so many

"Nothing worked i tried so many" - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As mentioned by DarkBee and melvio, the question is very vague and needs clearer specification.
That said, what you are talking about is either a so-called ragged hierarchy or an unbalanced one, or both. It's impossible to say from the description provided.
If a hierarchy has no children the drilldown will not be rendered by default. If you do have children the drill-down will be rendered. Having children but stopping the drilldown is non-sensical with regards to how hierarchies work.
